# Force HTTP while fetching page source with PHP

Tags: php, http, curl

How would I force HTTP (Not HTTPS), while getting the source code of: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YqEDdzf-nY?

I've tried using get_file_contents, but it goes to HTTPS.

Comment: they may not allow http but only https

Comment: You must be able to, you can use http with IE while connecting to YouTube

Comment: nope when i try the browser and use http its rewriting to https

Comment: Alright, but when I use IE, I can. So I know it's possible at least.

Comment: what ever browser, it alwasy turns http into https.

Comment: Why **don't** you want to use HTTPS?

Comment: It returns different tokens.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, because google forces you to use https. It will not accept longer unsecure connection.

They even start to [downrank websites, which are not on SSL](http://techcrunch.com/2014/08/07/google-says-website-encryption-or-lack-thereof-will-now-influence-search-rankings/).

---

As for your Comment, i have done a little bit more research.

Maybe it is [depended on the user-agent](https://superuser.com/a/653135). I have no time to confirm this.

Try [CURL](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php) with this User Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101
```

Comment: You must be able to, you can use http with IE while connecting to YouTube